# acts_as_commentable_with_threading - "build_from" method failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-commentable

In my comments controller, I have the following

class CommentsController < ApplicationController

```
  def create
    @comment_hash = params[:comment]
    #@comment = comment.new(comment_params)
    @obj = @comment_hash[:commentable_type].constantize.find(@comment_hash[:commentable_id])    
    @comment = Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, @comment_hash[:body])
    binding.pry
    #...
```

At the point where `binding.pry` is,

@comments_hash is

```
{"body=>"asdf comment body",
 "commentable_type"=>"Hack",
 "commentable_id"=>"2"}
```

@obj is

```
#<Hack id: 2, created_at: "2014-09-16 00:00:00",
updated_at: "2014-09-16 00:00:00", 
body: "some text", 
user_id: 1, 
comment_threads_count: 0>
```

But @comment outputs

```
#<Comment id: nil, 
commentable_id: 2, 
commentable_type: "Hack", 
title: nil, body: "asdf, 
comment body", 
subject: nil, 
user_id: 1, 
parent_id: nil, 
lfg: nil, rgt: 
nil, created_at: nil, 
updated_at: nil>
```

Why are so many things nil here? All my arguments for the `build_from` method are identical to before, when the code worked properly.

The terminal output when attempting to call `@comment.save` is

```
undefined method 'user' for #<Comment:0x5d1b1b0>
```

I'm not sure what this means. I have a user_id association. I don't see a user param in my params hash.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post your `Comment` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Substantial Your suspicion was correct.

Even though I the associations set up via the acts_as_commentable_with_threading method, I still had to do a `has_many` `belongs_to` association between the user and the comment. Once I added the `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship, things worked out. (and when I removed it again, it stopped working).

having `acts_as_commentable_with_threading` in the user model is for posting comments on the user, not specifying that the comment belongs to the user. So if you want to post comments on users, you need both that method, AND `has_many :comments` & `belongs_to :user` in the comment model

If you want just comments on another model, put the method in that model, and put `has_many :comments` in the user model, and `belongs_to :user` in the comment model